# How do I get the current selection in c#

Tags: c#

my question is how to get (in c#) the file/string/pic the user selected, the same thing Ctrl + C does, but without using the clipboard.

Example:
When I select some text in Word and run the code, it should return my selected text.

I could send a Ctrl + C and copy the clipboard but I search for a less dirty way.

Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to get the value only highlighted, not copied with Ctrl C ?

Comment: There's no universal way across all apps (other than the clipboard) - for Word you would use something like `Application.Selection`

Answer (score 1):

You can't just query for the selection of arbitrary data in the context of random processes. Each process (application) will control the selection the way it sees fit and the only reason the Clipboard mechanism works is because applications cooperate by handling the Ctrl-C key press a certain way (invoking the operating system clipboard functions to put data on the clipboard, and later retrieve it)